# Can’t compile this code due to lifetime issue

Tags: rust, lifetime

Compile this code:

```rust
fn foo<'a>(f: fn(&'a mut i32), x: &'a mut i32) {
    f(x);
    f(x);
}
```

I got the following error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*x` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src\main.rs:3:7
  |
1 | fn foo<'a>(f: fn(&'a mut i32), x: &'a mut i32) {
  |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
2 |     f(x);
  |     ----
  |     | |
  |     | first mutable borrow occurs here
  |     argument requires that `*x` is borrowed for `'a`
3 |     f(x);
  |       ^ second mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `scratch`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

But if I change the type of `f` from `fn(&'a mut i32)` to `fn(&mut i32)`, it compiles successfully, why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that the function `f` has an argument which is explicitly `'a`. This means that it **must** borrow its argument `x` for `'a`, which is its whole lifetime, leading to a double borrow error. You're looking for [higher-ranked trait bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html), which allow the function itself to have another generic lifetime that can shrink accordingly:

```rust
fn foo<'a>(f: for<'b> fn(&'b mut i32), x: &'a mut i32) {
    f(x);
    f(x);
}
```

Without specifying any explicit lifetimes, this is what Rust's lifetime infers.